# Cannot read a public array item inside chained AXIO transactions in VUE

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, axios

I have a chained AXIOS call that is being called from an array.  I need to have the second call finish before the first one makes another API request and the process works fine.  My only problem is that I can't reference anything from inside the response of the second chain.  I need to update either the calling array(arr) a public array this.excelData.results or even a deep copy of the original array.  Every time I get an error saying:

```
 err = TypeError: Cannot read property 'ORCID' of undefined at eval (webpack- 
    internal:///./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel- 
     loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue- 
    loader/lib/index.js?!./src/views/examples/ExcelWorksheet.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:410:49) at 
    NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>) at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/cache- 
   loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache- 
   loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/views/examples/ExcelWorksheet.vue? 
   vue&type=script&lang=js&:381:28) at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>) at eval (webpack- 
    internal:///./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel- 
    loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue- 
    loader/lib/index.js?!./src/views/examples/ExcelWorksheet.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:378:33)
```

I have tried adding this or self but nothing seems to help.  As I debug in a browser I can see all of the elements of the array but I can't read them in code or change them.  Is there something special that I need to do so that I can use the data from the second AXIOS call in the original array?

```
    lookUpORCID(){
   this.pubmedArticles=[];
   this.makeRequestsFromArray(this.excelData.results);
       },
          makeRequestsFromArray(arr) {

   var self = this
   let index = 0;
  function request() {

  let authorName =  arr[index]["Last_Name"]

  let linkGetIdList = 'https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?';
  linkGetIdList += 'tool=biosketch&db=pubmed&retmode=json&retmax=200&';
  linkGetIdList += 'term=' + authorName +'[AU] ';

    return axios.get(linkGetIdList).then((res) => { 
         index++;
         let idlist = res.data.esearchresult.idlist
         const passID = idlist.join(',')
        if (idlist.length > 0) {  
          var getXmlLink = 'https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?';
          getXmlLink += 'db=pubmed&retmode=xml&id=${passID}';         
          return axios.get(getXmlLink).then((response) => {
             // parse document
              const parser = new DOMParser()
              const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response.data, 'text/xml') // Get ALL XML content
              // Do Stuff

              **This is the spot that I need to change value in array**
              let xyz = arr[index]["ORCID"]



              return request(); 
          }) 
          }

        if (index >= arr.length) {
            return 'done'
        }
    });

}
return request();
```

},

Comment: You are able to access the `arr` or the error would have been `cannot read property index of undefined`.

You have incremented `index` after the first request & the `arr` has value `undefined` at the incremented `index`, so the error says `Cannot read property 'ORCID' of undefined`.

You can try `console.log(arr[index])` before `let xyz = arr[index]["ORCID"]` to verify above.

Comment: That was it.  Boy do I feel dumb.  I fixated on the wrong issue,  Vue is new to me and when I have to make self = this in areas I was not sure if it was something like that.  Thank you  Post it as an answer and I will give you credit for the correct answer

Comment: it happens ;), posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are able to access the `arr` or the error would have been: `cannot read property index of undefined`.

You have incremented `index` after the first request & the `arr` has the value `undefined` at the incremented `index`, so the error says `Cannot read property 'ORCID' of undefined`.

*You can try `console.log(arr[index])` before `let xyz = arr[index]["ORCID"]` to verify above.*